# Yii2: get data from list view to record with active record

Tags: javascript, activerecord, yii2

I am creating a questionnaire and I am trying to record the answers obtained, I am showing the questions in a `listview` which are obtained from one table (question) and I want to record them in another table (answer) using `active record`. I have tried to add the active form inside the itemView class but the send button appears duplicated every time I have more than 1 question, then I try to add it outside the itemView and if the submit button appears only once but I can't get it the data listed in itemView because I don't know how to send the fields of the active form to get the data from the itamView, I tried to send them by the render of the itemView but it throws me the Undefined variable error.

View

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
'enableClientValidation' => false,
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,]) ?>

<?= ListView::widget([
    'layout' => '<div class="pull-left">{items}</div>',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return $this->render('_answers',[
            'model' => $model, 
            'index' => $index
        ]);
    },
]); ?><div class="form-group">
<?php echo Html::submitButton('<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>'.' '.Yii::t('backend', 'Send') , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

View _answers

```
<td width="5%" class="vcenter" rowspan="3">
    <span class="panel-title-address"><label class="control-label">Nr: <?php echo ($index+1); ?></label></span>
</td>
<td width="95%" class="vcenter">
        <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-title required">
            <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-type_id"><?= Yii::t('backend', 'Question'.' : ')?></label>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-title required">
            <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-type_id"><?= $model->question ?></label>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $form->field($answer, 'answer')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

what I want to obtain is the `id` and `answer` of each question to be able to register them in the answer table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the undefined variable error because you are not passing the `$form` variable from your main view to `_answers.php`. You can pass it like this:

```php
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
'enableClientValidation' => false,
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,]) ?>

<?= ListView::widget([
    'layout' => '<div class="pull-left">{items}</div>',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) use ($form) {
        return $this->render('_answers',[
            'form' => $form,
            'model' => $model, 
            'index' => $index,
        ]);
    },
]); ?><div class="form-group">
<?php echo Html::submitButton('<span class="fa fa-plus"></span>'.' '.Yii::t('backend', 'Send') , ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

As for how to send multiple answers with the question ids you can either use the way mentioned in **vvpanchev's** answer or add a hidden field with question id. The `_answers.php` view with hidden field:

```
<td width="5%" class="vcenter" rowspan="3">
    <span class="panel-title-address"><label class="control-label">Nr: <?php echo ($index+1); ?></label></span>
</td>
<td width="95%" class="vcenter">
        <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-title required">
            <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-type_id"><?= Yii::t('backend', 'Question'.' : ')?></label>
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group field-qquestion-0-title required">
            <label class="control-label" for="qquestion-type_id"><?= $model->question ?></label>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php
            //set the question's id to answer model if you haven't done that already
            $answer->question_id = $model->id;
            //output the hidden input with question id
            echo \yii\helpers\Html::activeHiddenInput($answer, "[$index]question_id"); 
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->field($answer, "[$index]answer")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

If you use the hidden field approach then in your controller you can use `\yii\base\Model::loadMultiple()` method to load the data into answer models. You can also use `\yii\base\Model::validateMultiple()` for validation. I'm assuming the name for answer model class is `Answer`.

```php
$count = count(\Yii::$app->request->post('Answer', []));
$answers = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $answers[] = new Answer();
}
if (
    \yii\base\Model::loadMultiple($answers, \Yii::$app->request->post())
    && \yii\base\Model::validateMultiple($answers)
) {
    // ... save your answers and/or do other things needed
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have tried your solution but it only saves me the last record.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed to wrap `\Yii::$app->request->post('Answer', [])` this in `count()` function call. I've edited my answer to fix that. If it still doesn't make your code work you need to check if the form fields are named properly and if you properly save all your models from `$answers` array.

Comment: Now I have an error when I try to save a `checkboxList`, if I select 2 options it throws me the message  `Answer must be a string`, and when I select 1 it allows me to send but I have another error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Answer (score 0):

Change your answer input like this and you'll have answer input for every question:

```
<?php echo $form->field($answer, '['.$model->id.']answer')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

When you submit teh form, it will be submitted with all answer questions. So you can check and save the `$_POST` like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Answer']) and !empty($_POST['Answer'])){
    foreach($_POST['Answer'] as $question_id => $answer){
        //save your answer to your question
    }
}
```

You will have to change you ajaxvalidation too like this foreach